# Error when using pytest-asyncio with aiopg

Tags: pytest, fastapi, aiopg

I'm creating small educational app using fastapi and aiopg for connectioon to db.
It remains to write only the tests. I try to use pytest-asyncio and dependency overriding for connection to my test_db.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup_test_db():
    create_db()
    
    sql_script_path = "./db.sql"
    try:
        conn = ps.connect(DSN_TEST)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        with open(sql_script_path, "r") as script_file:
            sql_script = script_file.read()
            cursor.execute(sql_script)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    except ps.Error as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error initializing the test database: {e}")

    app.dependency_overrides[get_database_pool] = get_test_database_pool
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = get_test_db
    
    yield

    delete_db()

@pytest.fixture
async def ac():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        yield ac
```

and test itself

```py
async def test_root(ac: AsyncClient):
    response = await ac.get("/orders/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I specified in pytest.ini asyncio_mode = True, run pytest and get next error.

```
pool = await aiopg.create_pool(DSN_TEST)  # type: ignore
....\\Lib\\site-packages\\aiopg\\pool.py:300: in from_pool_fill
await self.\_fill_free_pool(False)
....\\Lib\\site-packages\\aiopg\\pool.py:336: in \_fill_free_pool
conn = await connect(
....\\Lib\\site-packages\\aiopg\\connection.py:65: in connect
connection = Connection(
....\\Lib\\site-packages\\aiopg\\connection.py:772: in __init__
self.\_loop.add_reader(

_______________________________________________________________________

self = \<ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False\>, fd = 884, callback = \<function Connection.\_ready at 0x0000011210F49080\>  
args = (\<weakref at 0x000001121331D080; to 'Connection' at 0x0000011213327990\>,)

    def add_reader(self, fd, callback, *args):

>       raise NotImplementedError

E       NotImplementedError

........\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\asyncio\\events.py:530: NotImplementedError\
```

Maybe someone know correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

I put this line before the test, and it fixes this up